# HTML Multi-level Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm kinda stuck. Mainly because I'm a novice. I need to be able to create expandable/collapse-able content online for use with self help. I have searched everywhere and cannot find exactly what I need. I need a plain vertical multi level menu system. I have almost what I need in the attached code. I think I am missing a final selector. Can any of you help me create the last needed selector? In this piece of code when I click on the sub sub menu, it collapses the parent menu, I need it to expand the sub sub menu? Help Please!

CSS Code

```
 #accordion ol {
        list-style: none;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;}
    #accordion ol li {
        height: 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
        transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: height 1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: height 1s ease-in;    
        overflow: hidden;}
    #accordion ol li ol:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0px;}
    #accordion ol li:target {
        height: 100px;}
    #accordion ol li ol{
        opacity: 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        border: 0px;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 80px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        transition: all 1s ease-in;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
        -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in;
        -o-transition: all 1s ease-in;}
    #accordion ol li:target ol{
        opacity: 1; }
```

HTML Code

```
<div class="page">    
        <nav id="accordion">
            <ol>
                <li id="item-1"><a href="#item-1"><span>Menu Item 1<span></a>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 1.1</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 1.2</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 1.3</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 1.4</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 1.5</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 1.6</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li id="item-2"><a href="#item-2"><span>Menu Item 2<span></a>
                    <ol>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 2.1</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 2.2</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 2.3</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li id="item-3"><a href="#item-3"><span>Menu Item 3<span></a>
                    <ol>
                         <li id="item-3.1"><a href="#item-3.1"><span>Menu Item 3.1<span></a>
                            <ol>
                            <li>Sub Menu Item 3.1.1</li>
                            <li>Sub Menu Item 3.1.2</li>
                            </ol>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 3.2</li>
                        <li>Sub Menu Item 3.3</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

### [Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHL7H/)

Comment: try the light weight and multilevel responsive menu -> github.com/hidaytrahman/hr-navigation-responsive-menu

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems:

I think your main problem is that once you change the active `:target` element by clicking `li#item-3.1`, the `:target` rules for menu level 2 (`#item-3`) no longer apply, so the submenu collapses back into its default state. I can't think of a good way to do a three level menu using this strategy, but I haven't put a lot of thought into it. My primary concern would be maintainability--your deeply nested, structure-dependent rules will quickly become hard to decipher and extend. If you're a CSS novice, I don't recommend this approach.

Another problem is that you're using values of `id` that include a dot ("`.`"). That's generally not good practice, since CSS selectors rely on the dot to indicate a class selector. While it's illegal to have a CSS class that begins with a number, it'll be cleaner to keep dots out of your `id` and `class` values altogether, to reduce confusion and special handling logic later.

A final question is whether you really should be using deeply nested menus like that in the first place. Deep menus are often a sign that you should rethink your application design. That's a guideline more than a hard and fast rule, and certain complex apps retain value from that structure, but most websites don't need it.